# Django forms validation fail

Tags: django

I have two fields in a form:

```
   names_field = CharField(
        label='Names',
        widget=Textarea(attrs={'rows': '10', 'placeholder': 'input names here ...'}))

    file_field = FileField(label='Upload from file')
```

Both are not required, but I can pass form.is_valid() only if I fill the both fields. It fails when I submit only one field names_field or file_field.

My view part:

```
form = AddNamessForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    ...
```

Comment: ou need to add `required=False` to these if you want to allow empty

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!

Answer (score 0):

I thought that required=False is a default value but it's not true.

```
   names_field = CharField(
        label='Names',
        reuired=False,
        widget=Textarea(attrs={'rows': '10', 'placeholder': 'input names here ...'}))

    file_field = FileField(label='Upload from file', reuired=False)
```